# r data.table: apply function with vector and matrix as parameters

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with the following columns:

```
OOSResults <-
  as.data.table(structure(
    list(
      c("1", "1", "1"),
      structure(c(17873, 17876, 17877), class = "Date"),
      c(48, 47, 55),
      c(22, 25, 20),
      c(31, 29, 25)
    ),
    .Names = c("score", "Date", "probH", "probD", "probA"),
    row.names = c(NA,-3L),
    class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
    sorted = "score"
  ))
```

-

Now I'd like to apply mLogLoss from ModelMetrics. It asks for

> Usage
>
> mlogLoss(actual, predicted)
>
> Arguments
>
> actual     A vector of the labels. Can be numeric, character, or factor
>
> predicted  matrix of predicted values. Can be matrix, data.frame

How can I apply this function to my data.table, still being able to use flexible ways of further analysing my data.table, i.e. LogLoss by date, any other column, without losing my data.table.

I tried:

```
OOSResults[, mapply(ModelMetrics::mlogLoss, score, as.matrix(probA/100,probD/100,probH/100))]
```

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: Please share some reproducible example. You can use dput(your.data.table) or if its too big use head()

Answer (score 1):

First question here, thanks for supporting me. After further trying I've got:

```
OOSResults2[,mlogLoss(score,as.data.frame(.(probH,probD,probA))),by=Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know how to compute `mlogLoss` for `score` with, for example, `probA`, which can be done like this:

```
ModelMetrics::mlogLoss(OOSResults$score, as.matrix(OOSResults$probA/100))
```

Now to compute it with the three different probability columns, you may do it using `mapply`, like this:

```
mapply(function(prob, by){ModelMetrics::mlogLoss(by, as.matrix(prob))}, 
       OOSResults[, c("probH", "probD", "probA")]/100,
       OOSResults[, "score"])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this would calculate individual log loss by single probability. The function above asks for a matrix of probabilities. And I'd like to apply it inside of my data.table. Is this possible?

Comment: That's what was understood by your question. Please show your expected output in the question.